# Angular 6 for IE11 resulting in blank window

Tags: angular, angular6, internet-explorer-11

So I have some issue with a project I'm working on--everything runs fine, except I'm trying to uncomment the import statements in the polyfill.ts for IE9, 10 and 11. I've uncommented everything and run npm install --save classlist.js and npm install --save web-animations-js. Everything builds and runs on chrome still, however it still doesn't run on IE11, any ideas behind this behavior? It opens with the angular logo on IE11, but just a blank screen.

am I missing something?
I have searched the internet and spoken with gitter to no avail.

I have found similar posts, but have not found a suitable answer.
(for example, [Angular 5 doesn't work in IE9 "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51391960/angular-5-doesnt-work-in-ie9-internet-explorer-cannot-display-the-webpage))

Found additional posts:
[angular 5 application is working on edge but failing on ie11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50160925/angular-5-application-is-working-on-edge-but-failing-on-ie11)

also

[Angular 2 / 4 / 5 not working in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140718/angular-2-4-5-not-working-in-ie11)

Attempted adding to index.html:
< meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> (added space to display)

Attempted adding to index.html:

and 
import 'core-js/client/shim';
to polyfill.ts

Polyfill.ts:

```
import "core-js/es7/reflect";
import "zone.js/dist/zone";

/* IE9, IE10 and IE11 */
 import "core-js/es6/array";
 import "core-js/es6/date";
 import "core-js/es6/function";
 import "core-js/es6/map";
 import "core-js/es6/math";
 import "core-js/es6/number";
 import "core-js/es6/object";
 import "core-js/es6/parse-float";
 import "core-js/es6/parse-int";
 import "core-js/es6/regexp";
 import "core-js/es6/set";
 import "core-js/es6/string";
 import "core-js/es6/symbol";
 import "core-js/es6/weak-map";
/* IE10 and IE11 for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import "classlist.js";  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/*added for testing purposes, no positive result.*/
//import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
//import 'core-js/client/shim';

/* IE10 and IE11 for Reflect API. */
 import "core-js/es6/reflect";

/* Web Animations */
 import "web-animations-js";  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.
```

Also:
Added

```
<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
```

to my index.html

Comment: Please show your code for `polyfills.ts`.

Comment: Alright, it's been added-- the commented out things have been added due to recommendations from other stack overflow pages, however--did not have an effect//produce the desired outcome.

Comment: and of course--like stated in OP, I did run the npm installs that are listed in the comments.  Thank you in advance for any help that you guys can offer!

Comment: do you get any errors from the console window of IE? (open the console window, then refresh the page)

Comment: Yes, I get two syntax errors:

Script1002: syntax error
Vendor.js (137,1)

Script1002: syntax error
main.js

and an 
HTML1506: Unexpected token
localhost:8095 (25,1)


and those refer to these lines:
in vendor.js:
class PlatformLocation {
}

in main.js

<app-layout></app-layout>

Comment: Have you looked at this thread - https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23927 ?

Comment: Looking at this... I guess I need to look into transpiling es6 to es5 using babel?  Is that the correct assumption?

Comment: And if so... am I just transpiling the code that is causing errors in IE (vendor.js and main.js)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using *Angular v7.*.** , you can solve it just follow the `polyfills.ts` in *src/polyfills.ts* and follow its inside tips like this:

```
/** IE9, IE10, IE11, and Chrome <55 requires all of the following polyfills.
 *  This also includes Android Emulators with older versions of Chrome and Google Search/Googlebot
 */

import "core-js/es6/symbol";
import "core-js/es6/object";
import "core-js/es6/function";
import "core-js/es6/parse-int";
import "core-js/es6/parse-float";
import "core-js/es6/number";
import "core-js/es6/math";
import "core-js/es6/string";
import "core-js/es6/date";
import "core-js/es6/array";
import "core-js/es6/regexp";
import "core-js/es6/map";
import "core-js/es6/weak-map";
import "core-js/es6/set";

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import "classlist.js"; // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
import "core-js/es6/reflect";
```

What you need to do is just to *uncomment* the lines above and install the another following:

```
npm install --save classlist.js
```

Again, `ng serve` you can check your result in IE 11 now.

Answer (score 6):

To resolve this issue, I:

```
1.  changed TSConfig to target ES5, and the module to es2015.
2.  I changed the order of the polyfills,
3.  I reran downloads for installing classlist.js and web-animations.js.
4.  and, I added:       < meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
to my html right below the meta tag <meta charset="utf-8">.
```

Not sure exactly which part of this solved my issue.  I ordered this list in the order in which I believe impacted the result.

Comment: All I needed to do was change TSConfig to target ES5.